# How to get custom cell label when segue?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to get the name of the selected row in the custom cell. How I can do that in Swift?

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var selectedCell = CustomCell()
    selectedCell = tableView(tbl, cellForRowAtIndexPath: <#NSIndexPath#>)

    if(segue.identifier == "next") {
        var next = (segue.destinationViewController as! EngineViewController)
        next.titleSub = selectedCell.cell.lblBrand.text
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you populate your table view with a data source? If so, get the value from your data source collection for the corresponding index.

Comment: Does your controller inherit from UITableViewController?

Comment: No it is a UIViewController @Carpsen90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you are just selecting a cell, the cell should be the sender.  Try this

```
if let selectedCell = sender as? CustomCell {
    if(segue.identifier == "next") {
    var next = (segue.destinationViewController as! EngineViewController)
    next.titleSub = selectedCell.cell.lblBrand.text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attempt to override didSelectRowAtIndexPath to get your cell.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.yourLabel.textYouWant
let yourViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController
    navigationController?.pushViewController(yourViewController, animated: true)
```

}

Comment: I can't over override (Method doesn't override any method from its superclass) and I'm using segue